# what is Local Objects, Favorite Packages, System Library in ABAP project

Tags: abap

I am a java programmer, I just started working on ABAP. I installed ABAP plugin for Eclipse Neon.

When I created an ABAP project in Eclipse, it creates following hierarchy.

[image]

Can any one explain me what are these three hierarchys. Is System Library is the collection of packages that are given by SAP itself?

It will be great, if you provide any reference links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `Local Objects` you can find development objects like reports, which don't have a target system to be transported to.

`System Library` contains all packages developed by SAP or your company/customer.

If you frequently develop a package, you can also mark it as favorite. Those will be displayed under `Favorite Packages` then.